# Changing the value of a parameter based on spread operator

Tags: javascript

So let's say that I have an object literal, which is the following:

```
let test = {
  settings: {
    title: '',
    has_content: true,
    can_edit: false,
  }
}
```

Now I have another object literal as shown below:

```
let test2 = {
  ...test,
  settings: {
    can_edit: true,
  }
}
```

How can I bring over all the parameters from the `test` object literal but have the ability to change values in `test2`?

So ultimately, I'd like for this:

```
let test2 = {
    settings: {
      title: '', (This is default)
      can_edit: true, (This value is changed)
      has_content: true, (This is default)
    }
}
```

Now, when I `console.log test2`, all that I see in the settings is the `can_edit: true`, but not the `title` or `has_content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spread the `test.settings` in `test2.settings` to merge the properties and override with the latest one that are defined in `test2.settings`.

```js
let test = {
  settings: {
    title: "",
    has_content: true,
    can_edit: false,
  },
};

let test2 = {
  settings: {
    ...test.settings,
    can_edit: true,
  },
};

console.log(test2);
```

Comment: Thanks so much De! I didn't know that the spread was multi-level object specific also, learned something new!

Comment: @DevSem You are more than welcome, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you `test.settings` key will be replaced by `test2.settings`. so you should spread the `test.setting` into `test2.settings` like below

```js
let test = {
  settings: {
    title: '',
    has_content: true,
    can_edit: false,
  }
}

let test2 = {
  settings: {
    ...test.settings,
    can_edit: true,
  }
}
   
console.log(test2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
let test2 = {
   ...test,
   settings: {
     ...test.settings,
     can_edit: true,
   }
}
```

Explanation: You need to spread object by object. Be aware, if you use the spread before changing the values (like I did) your changes survive.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Christian! Learned that the spreader can be used on inner objects and not just the parent, good learning curve this morning.